# Growth rates slower than logarithmic?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, recreational-mathematics

So far, I've been able to determine growth rates using the following limit:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$Which, if need be, can be solved with calculus.

From this, I deduced that it is very difficult to have a function $f(x)$ that grows slower than a function $g(x)=\ln(x)$.

I noted a few, the Lambert W function, or something simple like $\sqrt{\ln(x)}$.  This means we are excluding composite functions.

However, I wondered if there are any "parent" functions that have slower growth rates than a logarithm.

This is excluding non-elementary things like the Lambert W function or the inverse factorial.

And by "parent" function, I mean you cannot combine multiple $x$'s or apply multiple operations to $x$.

That is, we can't try to do something silly like $\ln[\ln(x)]$ or $x-\ln(x)$.

One function, one operation, elementary functions only.  By elementary functions, I define an elementary function as being analytic and algebraic, unlike the inverse factorial or Lambert W function or similar things.

Can we have growth slower than logarithmic under these restrictions?

**EDIT**

One last restriction.  The proposed function $g(x)$ must have the following:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$$

Because it has come to my attention that horizontal asymptotes may apply.

Comment: So, just to be clear ... You are seeking a function with limit equal to infinity as its argument approaches infinity, but you are excluding all "non-elementary" functions along with all composite functions of elementary functions and operations of elementary functions. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, that is what I mean, I think.

Comment: @Dr.MV Feel free to edit my question if you think you can word it any better.

Comment: What do you mean by "elementary functions" here?

Comment: The [Inverse of Achermann's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) is quite slow...

Comment: @Wojowu By elementary functions, I am most likely referring to functions that aren't too special.  I'm sorry if it is a little vague.

Comment: I'm confused. If non-elementary functions and compositions of elementary functions are both forbidden, what's left?

Comment: @user7530 I don't know.  If I knew what was left, the answer wouldn't be hard for me to find.

Comment: What about compositions of such functions? E.g., $\log\log$ is slower than $\log$.

Comment: You need to give us a specific definition of "elementary function" in order to possibly expect us a reasonable answer as to "what's left".

Comment: @Wojowu Give me some time to think on that.

Comment: @Wojowu I have defined my elementary function

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis I have refined my question, stating you cannot use compositions.  I've also restricted this to analytic and algebraic functions.

Comment: Is it fair to say that your question is thus the following: "can an algebraic function that diverges at $\infty$ have slower growth than $\log x$"?

Comment: @SimpleArt Just asking, are you aware logarithmic functions aren't algebraic?

Comment: @Wojowu I am aware.  However, you can't choose the logarithmic function as your answer.

Comment: @user7530 Well, I'm sorry.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make it a better question?

Comment: Make it clear at the begining what you mean by elementary, ie "I am looking for a **analytic and algebraic** function whose limit to infinity is infinity and which grows slower than ln(x)". Or really just clarify what is the "parent" function all about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)$ is an algebraic function which tends to infinity as $x$ tends to infinity. We can rewrite the algebraic equation which it satisfies to a form $a_n(f(x))x^n+...+a_1(f(x))x+a_0(f(x))=0$, where $a_i$ are polynomials and $a_n$ is nonzero. Let $d$ be the largest of the degrees of $a_i$. I claim $f(x)$ can't grow slower than $x^{1/(d+2)}$, by which I mean $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^{1/(d+2)}}=0$. If this were the case, then we would have, for large $x$, $$|a_{n-1}(f(x))x^{n-1}+...+a_1(f(x))x+a_0(f(x))|\leq|a_{n-1}(f(x))|x^{n-1}+...+|a_1(f(x))|x+|a_0(f(x))|\leq x^{(d+1)/(d+2)}x^{n-1}+...+x^{(d+1)/(d+2)}x+x^{(d+1)/(d+2)}<x^n\leq |a_n(f(x))x^n|$$
where second inequality is true because $a_i(f(x))<f(x)^{d+1}<(x^{1/(d+1)})^{d+2}$ for $f(x)$ sufficiently large. If you look closely, this implies that $f(x)$ cannot satisfy assumed inequality for large $x$.

This allows us to answer your question in **negative**: every algebraic function which tends to infinity isn't slower than some power function, so can't grow slower than logarithmic function.